# how to Zoom only outer div not inner divs

Tags: html, css, zooming

I zoom a `div` using `-moz-transform: scale(3.2)`, but I only want to zoom the outer div and not the content (other divc) within that div.

**here is my code**

```html
<div id="div1" style="-moz-transform: scale(3.2);" >
    <div id="div2">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I zoom the `div1`, however `div2` also zooms. I only want to zoom `div1` but not `div2`, meaning that the content of `div2` will still be displayed as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `-moz-transform: scale(0.3125)` to offset the parent scale. Basically `0.3125 = 1 / 3.2` where 3.2 is the scale factor applied to the parent.

```html
<div id="div1" style="-moz-transform: scale(3.2);-webkit-transform: scale(3.2); transform: scale(3.2);" >
         <div id="div2" style="-moz-transform: scale(.3125);-webkit-transform: scale(.3125); transform: scale(.3125);">
             content
           </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works well in Chrome, but does not work inIE/mozilla properly :(

Comment: you need to use browser prefix for transform
`-ms-transform: scale(0.3125);`
`-moz-transform: scale(0.3125);`
`-webkit-transform: scale(0.3125);`
`transform: scale(0.3125);`

Answer (score 1):

You can invert a CSS `scale` by applying the reciprocal scale value on the child, e.g. if you have `transform: scale(4);` on the parent you need scale `1/4` on the child: `transform: scale(0.25);`:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#div1 {
  transform: scale(4);
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 100px;
}
#div2 {
  transform: scale(0.25);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, you need `transform: scale(0.3125);`, the reciprocal of `3.2`.